# Send html newsletter with css

Tags: html, css

how to create a html newsletter

if i have a page

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 style="color: red; background:yellow">hello world</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

how can I send this by email? If i paste on my email, it only show text with all tag.

I mean sending the newsletter, like others company's newsletter

Comment: How do you send the email? What is the content type?

Comment: Not enough information provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you means sending emails in html.
If it is right,I hope here is what you want

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
This is an email link:
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">
Send Mail</a>
</p>

<p>
<b>Note:</b> Spaces between words should be replaced by %20 to ensure that the browser will display the text properly.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Or Do you want to send html page in email.
you can find at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?hl=en
if you are using gmail.

Comment: i mean sending the newsletter

Comment: so attach your newsletter file which is save with html in your compose mail and sent it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean manual copy/paste directly into rich-text email - don't copy/paste HTML source. View the content in browser (where colors and backgrounds actually show) and copy/paste that *rendered* content.